# List style stops displaying roman numerals after index 4000

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, loops

I've created a simple list from 0 to 10,000, where each `li` has a style type of `upper-roman`, a random background color as well as a child `abbr` to display hexadecimal string of the color.

When running the program I the list style changes from `upper-roman` to `decimal` after index 4000.

Can anyone explain to me what's happening here?

**NOTE:  Running the test takes a few seconds.**

```js
$(document).ready(readyHandler);

function readyHandler()
{
 var $list = $("#MyList");
 
 for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
 {
  $list.append("<li><abbr title=\"\">Auto Insert " + i + "</abbr></li>");
 } 
 
 colors = [];
 
 for (let i = 0; i < $list.children().length; i++)
 {
  colors.push(getRandomColor());
 }
 
 $list.children().each(listItemsHandler);
}

function listItemsHandler(index, item)
{
 var $target = $(item);
 var color = colors[index];
 
 $target.css("background-color", color);
 $target.find("abbr").attr("title", color);
}

function getRandomColor()
{
 var color = "#";
 
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
  var part = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
  
  color += (part.length > 1) ? part : "0" + part;
 }
 
 return color;
}
```

```css
#MyList
{
 list-style-type: upper-roman;
 margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id = "MyList"></ol>
```

Comment: [Here's a faster fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbcqasr2/1/) - it helps to do just one DOM update :)

Comment: And yes that sure does look like a Firefox bug to me.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1056111

Comment: I found somthing here (see «Limitations Of Numbered Lists») : http://www.mrinitialman.com/Library/HTML/Chapters/CSS/CSS-Lists.html

Comment: @Pointy does it in Chrome too... Not a FF bug.

Comment: Yes agreed, after reading about it it's more like a "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"

Comment: The W3C tests all seem to agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 4000, roman numerals begin to include the over-line which doesn't have an ASCII representation for display in plain text. For example, 4000 is `IV` with a line over the top.  For this reason, there is no way for browser renderers to represent the numeral in `char` form as a `<li>` bullet.

The only way to represent this would be with an ADDITIONAL css property `overline`.

In short, it is not possible to represent numerals over 3999 as bullet items.

Comment: You could, however, write your own logic to convert your integers to roman numerals and write your own DOM to represent the list and then include the `overline` on 4000+

Comment: I wondered why not use MMMM and found a really instructive reference on this. Roman numbering rules evolved in time. So, MMMM was the way to represent it 3000 years ago. Then,  IVbar was introduced. But both ways coexisted between 3000 and 1500 years ago. And now, only IVbar is correct. Ref: http://able2know.org/topic/54469-1

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes sir. That's correct. But for the sake of legacy, I wonder why browsers don't just use the olden days syntax... then I realized it would require an almost infinite reference table and display at 10,000+ would be absurd and break most interfaces.

Comment: And that not all... The bar over is not the only difference with decimal numbers. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers

Comment: @DanChill Sorry if I'm late to the party, but I must complain about your use of "ASCII". Other list counters, like `hiragana-iroha` use the whole range of Unicode, so there wouldn't really be a reason for `upper-roman` to restrict itself to ASCII.You could use V with a U+0305 for 5000.